# How to eliminate error: "Implied eval is evil"

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm trying to make my code JavaScript "strict", so I'm running it through [JSLint](http://JSLint.com) to ensure my code is compliant.

However, on the following code:

```
setTimeout("getExtJs()", 2000);
```

I receive the following error:

> Implied eval is evil. Pass a function instead of a string.

How do I make my code JavaScript "strict"?

Comment: See [Implied eval is evil](https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/implied-eval.md#when-do-i-get-this-error).

Answer (score 14):

```
setTimeout(getExtJs, 2000);
```

Note that there are no quotes around getExtJs, I am passing the function not a String.

**EDIT:**
As noted in the comments the reason why JSLint is upset is that when the first argument is a String it is processed as code to be executed in the same manner as eval()

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout

To find out why eval() (and by extension using Strings as the 1st argument here) is evil see the [Mozilla Developer Network entry for `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21).

Comment: +1. But for absolute completeness, you might want to add how strings are eval'd if passed as the first argument, while expressions are not.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't complain if you do:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // your code of this function getExtJs here
}, 2000);
```

Or:

```
setTimeout(getExtJs, 2000);
```

Although I don't see anything wrong in your implementation security-wise or otherwise.

Comment: As a side note - it's not a good idea to use an anonymous function to execute another function that could be called by name.  Only use anonymous functions if you intend for one-time execution that is never repeated elsewhere, or if you have major scoping requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Like it says, pass in the function (no quotes around the function name):

```
setTimeout(getExtJs, 2000);
```

When you pass in a string (`"getExtJs"`), `setTimeout` end up `eval`ing it. Instead of that, it is better to simply pass in the function itself (`getExtJs`).

Comment: This will set the result of getExtJs() as the first parameter to setTimeout, which is probably not the desired effect.

Comment: this will execute the function immediately and run whatever `getExtJs` returns 2 seconds from now, which is not what the OP does.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function () {getExtJs();}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
setTimeout(getExtJs, 2000);
```

You pass a reference to the function, and after 2000ms the function is executed. If you put parens after the function name, you are executing the function instead of referencing it.