# Why isn't my slideshow not working within my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I coded a simple slideshow with Javascript but it isn't working when I place it within my HTML page that I have created. So far I have tried to include it in different areas, different div's and from an external file. Nothing seems to be working. I have tested the code on blank HTML and it works. But when I use it within the page that I have put together, it wont load.

```js
var i = 0;      // Start Point
var images = []; // Images Array
var time = 3000; // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "gotpic1.jpg";
images[1] = "gotpic2.jpg";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
  document.slide.src = images[i];

  // Check If Index Is Under Max
  if (i < images.length - 1){
    // Add 1 to Index
    i++; 
  } else { 
    // Reset Back To O
    i = 0;
  }

  // Run function every x seconds
  setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload = changeImg;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.gotlogo{
  text-align: center; 
}
.slider {
  border: solid black 2p
}
.slider{
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body style=" background-image: url(&quot;forest1.jpg&quot;);">
  <div class="gotlogo">
    <img src="gotlogo2.png" alt="GOT">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img name="slide" height="200" width="400">
  </div>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Have you tried to do some debugging with the developer tools?

Comment: Try to [output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) something from your function. See if it's firing and what it's doing.

Comment: @ADyson To be honest with you, I'm not sure how to check for console errors but the only the message that came up when I pasted it into jsfiddle was "implied eval, consider passing a function instead of a string" . That message was displayed next to the setTimeout portion of the code. I'm not really sure how to use developer tools to debug yet. Would you recommend that?

Comment: What if you do `setTimeout(changeImg, time);`?

Comment: @showdev Ok I think I did this right, so outside of the function I did a "console.log(changeImg())" and it gave me this message "TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined (/index.js:13)"

Comment: @showdev I gave it shot but nothing displayed within the div tag that I have the HTML img code set in.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe that kind of [dot notation only works inside forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020289/why-can-only-forms-be-referenced-by-dot-notation)? It might be worth investigating.

Comment: By the way, see [How to eliminate error: “Implied eval is evil”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167689/how-to-eliminate-error-implied-eval-is-evil).

Comment: @showdev thank you for the links. I'm going to read through them to have a better understanding of what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully I can improve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there are a lot to of room for improvements, for now I'm giving you a working prototype of your version of code. Just added an id to the `<img/>` and how src is manipulated in changeImg()

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body style=" background-image: url(&quot;forest1.jpg&quot;);">
  <div class="gotlogo"> <img src="gotlogo2.png" alt="GOT"> </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img name="slide" id="slide" height="200" width="400">
  </div>
  <p><br>
  </p>
  <script>
    var i = 0; // Start Point
    var images = []; // Images Array
    var time = 3000; // Time Between Switch

    // Image List
    images[0] = "http://www.buyersgohappy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/GOT-Kingdom-in-India-11-750x339.jpg";
    images[1] = "https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/010/576/got.jpg";


    // Change Image
    function changeImg() {
      document.getElementById("slide").src = images[i];

      // Check If Index Is Under Max
      if (i < images.length - 1) {
        // Add 1 to Index
        i++;
      } else {
        // Reset Back To O
        i = 0;
      }

      // Run function every x seconds
      setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    }

    // Run function when page loads
    window.onload = changeImg;
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .gotlogo {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .slider {
      border: solid black 2px
    }
    
    .slider {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Having that said, let's see how you can improve your code. Please checkout the changeImg() function:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body style=" background-image: url(&quot;forest1.jpg&quot;);">
  <div class="gotlogo"> <img src="gotlogo2.png" alt="GOT"> </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img name="slide" id="slide" height="200" width="400">
  </div>
  <p><br>
  </p>
  <script>
    var i = 0; // Start Point
    var images = []; // Images Array
    var time = 3000; // Time Between Switch

    // Image List
    /*
    For local images:
    say you have a local folder structure like this:
    
    GOT
    |
    --> index.html (this file)
    |
    --> Images
        |
        --> got1.jpg
        |
        --> got2.jpg
        
    Now in you can can these images like:
    images[0] = "Images/got1.jpg"
    images[1] = "Images/got2.jpg"
    
    Let's try another example folder structure:
    
    GOT
    |
    --> Html
    |   |
    |   --> index.html (this file)
    |
    --> Images
        |
        --> got1.jpg
        |
        --> got2.jpg
        
    Now in you can can these images like:
    images[0] = "../Images/got1.jpg"
    images[1] = "../Images/got2.jpg"
    
    */
    images[0] = "http://www.buyersgohappy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/GOT-Kingdom-in-India-11-750x339.jpg";
    images[1] = "https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/010/576/got.jpg";


    // Change Image
    function changeImg() {
      document.getElementById("slide").src = images[i];

      // Keep index under the size of images array
      i = (i+1) % images.length;
    }

    // Run function when page loads
    window.onload = function() {
      // Run function every x seconds
      setInterval(changeImg, time);
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .gotlogo {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .slider {
      border: solid black 2px
    }
    
    .slider {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think you read my mind with the Game of Thrones images ;)

Comment: I have one additional question for you. I integrated the code you helped me with but it will only show pictures from web links. I'm trying to use game of thrones pictures stored on my computer but they are not showing up for some reason. Would you have any idea of whats going on?

Comment: For that you have to put a relative path in the place of the web link. Also the local path would be relative. meaning, if the pictures and html are in the same folder, just put the name of the pictures and it will get picked up. Else, you gotta put the relative path. If you don't understand, tell me your folder structure and so that I can give you an working example quickly.

Comment: Ok I think this is how it looks, c:\users\pc\documents\HTML TEST(folderwhere"gotpic1jpg" is stored)

Comment: I've added some comments in the second script of my answer. That would give you the basics. In case you are still confused, let me know the location of your html file and I'll tell you the exact relative path to put.

Comment: Ok I have the pictures in the same file as the HTML file but the images are not in a separate folder. I'm not sure which file path to use for it. Here is the direct file path: C:\Users\Home Gaming PC\Documents\HTML TEST\GOT PROJ\gotpic1.jpg

Comment: What I'm gathering here is, there is a folder on your PC with 3 files: index.html, gotpic1.jpg, gotpic2.jpg. If this describes your case correctly, just put images[0] = "gotpic1.jpg";

Comment: " just put images[0] = "gotpic1.jpg" This is what I tried first but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Are you certain that gotpic1.jpg and index.html are in the same folder? If not, place them inside the same folder and see if it gets picked up.

Comment: I just double checked and you were right, they were not. I placed the gotpic1.jpg file inside the same folder as the HTML file and it worked!! Thank you for helping me with this!!

Comment: Now if you want to still work being the html and the jpg in different folders, checkout my 2nd script in the original answer. I tried to make it visual for you to understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

u are using old fashioned way  u maybe be practicing  i just changed a bitin code

i used `getElementsByName()` function to find  element

```js
var i = 0;      // Start Point
var images = []; // Images Array
var time = 3000; // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg";
images[1] = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
  document.getElementsByName('slide')[0].src = images[i];

  // Check If Index Is Under Max
  if (i < images.length - 1){
    // Add 1 to Index
    i++; 
  } else { 
    // Reset Back To O
    i = 0;
  }

  // Run function every x seconds
  setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads
window.onload = changeImg;
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.gotlogo{
  text-align: center; 
}
.slider {
  border: solid black 2p
}
.slider{
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body style=" background-image: url(&quot;forest1.jpg&quot;);">
  <div class="gotlogo">
    <img src="gotlogo2.png" alt="GOT">
  </div>
  <div class="slider" name='w'>
    <img name="slide" height="200" width="400">
  </div>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! I think you read my mind with the Game of Thrones images ;) I created this from following a tut that was made in 2017. Thank you for the help. So I'm assuming that the way that I did it is no longer correct?

Comment: I'm trying to use pictures from my PC. When I change the links and add the file name to the strings, the code isn't pulling the images through for some reason. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: give me code or link u are adding p.s i think u should learn directory listing