# Implied eval. Consider passing a function instead of a string?

Tags: javascript

apologies for asking this when I've seen other threads where it was asked (similarly) but I"m not understanding the recommendations in previous posts. I'm very inexperienced with javascript and muddle through it here and there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to create a countdown timer to a specific date. Locally the counter seems fine and it runs but upon going onto a dev environment is the an error:

"Implied eval. Consider passing a function instead of a string"

Here is the code I'm using:

```
 function updateTimer() {
 future = Date.parse("aug 24, 2022 01:30:00");
 now = new Date();
 diff = future - now;

 days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
 mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
 secs = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

 d = days;
 h = hours - days * 24;
 m = mins - hours * 60;
 s = secs - mins * 60;

 document.getElementById("timer")
  .innerHTML =
  '<div style="display:inline-block; min-width:90px; padding:15px; background:#000000; border-radius:10px; border:2px solid #0d0d0d; margin:6px;">' + d + '<span style="color: #58595B; display: block; margin-top: 6px; font-size: .35em; font-weight: 400;">DAYS</span></div>' +
  '<div style="display:inline-block; min-width:90px; padding:15px; background:#000000; border-radius:10px; border:2px solid #0d0d0d; margin:6px;">' + h + '<span style="color: #58595B; display: block; margin-top: 6px; font-size: .35em; font-weight: 400;">HOURS</span></div>' +
  '<div style="display:inline-block; min-width:90px; padding:15px; background:#000000; border-radius:10px; border:2px solid #0d0d0d; margin:6px;">' + m + '<span style="color: #58595B; display: block; margin-top: 6px; font-size: .35em; font-weight: 400;">MINUTES</span></div>' +
  '<div style="display:inline-block; min-width:90px; padding:15px; background:#000000; border-radius:10px; border:2px solid #0d0d0d; margin:6px;">' + s + '<span style="color: #58595B; display: block; margin-top: 6px; font-size: .35em; font-weight: 400;">SECONDS</span></div>';
}
setInterval('updateTimer()', 1000);
```

The error is on the last line.

Thank you in advance

Comment: *"...I"m not understanding the recommendations in previous posts..."* Please link the posts with the solutions you didn't understand.

Comment: So use `setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);` instead?

Comment: The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167689/how-to-eliminate-error-implied-eval-is-evil) seem quite clear. Don't pass a string to `setInterval`. Pass a function reference: `setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);`.

Comment: Oh wow, ok yeah. It's more of ignorance on my side of not understanding some of the terms still. 

I don't have the links to the previous threads handy, they more than likely worked but made sense just not to me, yet.

Thank you